# <Super>-Right for tile window right does not work in Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, window-management

Xubuntu 22.04

I use super-left and super-right a lot on my widescreen monitor. Super-left to tile a window to left half of screen works fine. Super-right does not do anything. I've not changed any shortcuts, this is on a fresh install of 22.04.

Not sure how to proceed with debugging it!

edit: tile down also works - tile up does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove those shortcuts in the settings (in "window manager" settings). Interestingly, it has to be done twice, since the first attempt to erase them exposes a second set of key combinations. Then reassign them again.

Comment: Wowsers, that works! Is there an issue tracker or something for Xubuntu I should raise this on?

Comment: @brabster Yep, I think this is it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Removing them twice is the key here. Very annoying that there are lots of small bugs like this in Ubuntu 22.04 that weren't there in the previous versions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this bug was annoying me.

Comment: Came with the same problem and it worked, thank you